# Live assets compilation only for one file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets, precompile

There is **config.assets.compile=true** parameter which enables so called "live compilation".
I need Rails to compile one specific asset (sample.css.scss.erb) on each request in live mode but the rest of assets should be still precompiled.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - put `sample.css.scss.erb` in a path different from `config.assets.manifest (default="public/assets")` and add it with `javascript_include_tag`

Option 2 - Remove it from the config.assets.precompile

```
config.assets.precompile -= %w( sample.css.scss.erb )
```

Make sure you clean then precompile to test it.

I did not test either option, please let us know if any works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Live compilation for file is required when css is preprocessed by .css.erb file.
It means dynamically compiling css.

For example : allowing users to set the colors and would like to conditionally use "live compilation"

In that case i will suggest dynamically rendering /users/:id/styles.css.erb instead of live compilation.

Reason there might be millions of users and in production environment using Ec2 instance will cost you more. That's why i will suggest below solution:

First define your custom action on the `UsersController`:

```
# config/routes.rb
match '/users/:id/styles' => 'users#styles', :as => :user_styles
```

Link to the "stylesheet" in your layout:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', user_styles_path(current_user, :format => 'css')
```

Define the action in your controller. You could do whatever you want to retrieve the user's preferences here:

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def styles
    @colors = User.find(params[:id]).colors
  end
end
```

That action will automatically render this view:

```
# app/views/users/styles.css.scss.erb
$background-color: <%= @colors[:background] %>;

body {
  background-color: $background-color;
}
```

More ideas and suggetions are most welcome.